# sfdx force:org:create error "IndustriesActionPlan is not a valid Features value."

Tags: salesforcedx-cli

I'm getting an error creating a scratch org with the IndustriesActionPlan feature.  This was working about 2-3 weeks ago, but now something is different.

I'm using the command on the command line

```
sfdx force:org:create -f config/project-scratch-def.json
```

with version
sfdx-cli/7.36.0-b1c4e9c7c8 darwin-x64 node-v10.15.3

I've removed all plugins (i had the local dev server plugin installed, but since removed it to see if that affected anything).

my project definition file looks like the following, and again, this def file was working a few weeks ago (pre-dreamforce):

```
{
  "orgName": "My Org",
  "adminEmail": "<removed email>",
  "edition": "Enterprise",
  "features": [
    "ContactsToMultipleAccounts",
    "FinancialServicesUser:10",
    "IndustriesActionPlan",
    "PersonAccounts"
  ],
  "settings": {
    "lightningExperienceSettings": {
      "enableS1DesktopEnabled": true
    }
  }
}
```

and I should also mention, I'm running on a Mac.

Thanks in advance for any clue's anyone can give me!

Comment: This appears to be happening again in version Winter '21

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a [Salesforce known issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000001GKfdQAG) currently under review.

Unfortunately, there is no workaround. You could indicate that this issue affects you to follow up on the resolution.