# sfdx “IndustriesActionPlan is not a valid Features value.” in Winter '21

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org, scratch-org-definition-file

A little while ago an issue showed up on the `winter '21` version where sfdx force:org:create throws the error `IndustriesActionPlan is not a valid Features value.`

I am aware that this was fixed in a previous version but this is happening again (see [sfdx force:org:create error "IndustriesActionPlan is not a valid Features value."](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/287915/sfdx-forceorgcreate-error-industriesactionplan-is-not-a-valid-features-value)).

Is there anyway to enable ActionPlans on a scratch org without listing the feature `IndustriesActionPlan` in your scratch org config file?

Here is what my config file looks like (this stopped working after winter '21 was rolled out):

```json
{
    "orgName": "Test Scratch Org",
    "edition": "Developer",
    "hasSampleData": false,
    "features": [
        "IdentityProvisioningFeatures"
    ],
    "settings": {
        "lightningExperienceSettings": {
            "enableS1DesktopEnabled": true
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An investigation has been raised with the Salesforce product team recently and it has been identified as a known bug. The fix will go in one of the upcoming Winter'21 patch releases - by end of this week (safe harbor)

****Problem**:** Customers using the "IndustriesActionPlan" feature cannot create scratch orgs.
Expected result: Scratch orgs can be created using this feature.
Actual result: Scratch org creation fails with "ERROR running force:org:create: IndustriesActionPlan is not a valid Features value."

**Steps To Reproduce:**

1. Create a definition file with the IndustriesActionPlan feature.
2. Create a scratch org using the definition file.
3. The org creation will fail with "ERROR running force:org:create: IndustriesActionPlan is not a valid Features value."

**Solution:**

A Bug-fix has been submitted. The solution is to wait for this fix to be live on customer orgs, there are no workarounds available at this time.

Comment: Thank you Anudeep. Will keep an eye out for a patch.

Comment: Confirmed that after the patch, this is now working like it used to. Thank you so much Anudeep.

Comment: You are welcome!